# Powershell copy-item creates a folder instead of copying file

Tags: powershell, webdav, copy-item

I mapped a webdav folder with new-psdrive, cd to a folder, then try to copy one file to a local folder. The script code (draft) is the following:

```
New-PSDrive -Name WEBDAV -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\testserver@SSL\davwwwroot\myApp"
cd WEBDAV:
cd "notes\user"
Copy-Item -Path ".\important.txt" -Destination "c:\temp"
```

What I see, that after the Copy-Item a new empty FOLDER "C:\temp\important.txt" is created. Not a file. When I change the "copy-item" command to "robocopy" it works perfectly. I am wondering what is wrong with the copy-item... How could I use it to do the work?!

Comment: have you confirmed that the source is NOT a dir? if you do `Get-Item` on it and then run `.GetType()` on that ... what does it report?

Comment: which powershell version and platform are you referring? cannot reproduce with Win10

Comment: Mapped as W: and still the same. Powershell version is 5.1.18362.752, it is a Windows 10 Enterprise build 18363. The webdav server is a "our-own" webdav server, our IT team developed and implemented the webdav protocol on it. The LS cmdlet just before the copy-item lists the important.txt as a file item: LastWriteTime : 10/17/2019 10:22:51 AM
Length        : 33490521
Name          : important.txt

Comment: Interesting, the get-item says "PSIsContainer     : True", and "Attributes        : Directory
Mode              : d-----" There should be the problem! Hm! Thanks for the question @Lee_Dailey! May the protocol implementation is bad :(

Comment: @ZoltanHernyak - that is your problem ... the source item seems to be a dir. [*grin*] that needs to be fixed ...

Answer (score 2):

simply specify the file name:

```
Copy-Item -Path ".\important.txt" -Destination "c:\temp.txt"
```

Comment: Interesting - but it is the same. Creates an empty folder instead of copying a file. I think the webdav env causes some difference.

Comment: did you try mapping with "normal" net use to e.g. Z-drive and use the Z-drive? any different?